# How can I use DEFAULT values via knex insert?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sql-insert, default, knex.js

My goal is to dynamically insert data into a table via knex.

Code looks like this:

```js
const knexService = require("../knexService.js")


async function insertObjectToKnex() {
    const insertObject = {
        id: "DEFAULT",
        someKey: "someValue"
    };

    await knexService.db("table").insert(inserObject);
}
```

On `DEFAULT` the next free id should be used as database id - table is configured and it works with raw sql. With knex.js I get the following error:

`invalid input syntax for type integer: "DEFAULT"`

Using the `useNullAsDefault: true,` config is not possible, because the id is not nullable.

How can I trigger the default value in knex - I did not find anything in the documentation or with google, that could at least give a hint to this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is not mentioned in the documentation of knex.js one should simply not add fields with a DEFAULT assignement to a query. This will set the default value to the row column.